# PyGame Player and Ball Position is not appearing at same spot

Tags: python, pygame

### PyGame Player and Ball Position

Hello, i'm writing a small game using PyGame, however, i'm trying to set a Game Over state if the ball touched the player (both stacked on same Position). So far i have created the player image also drawn the ball using the pygame.draw.circle function also forced a static position on game start to both the ball and player object to posx = 320, posy = 240, to activate the check if gameLose function (checks if the ball and player has same position).

The issue i'm facing is that the print position function for both ball and player prints that they are on the same position, but apparently in game window they are not. Look here https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwNqb.jpg (image link, sorry i cant directly paste it due to low reputation)

('Player Pos', (320, 240))
('Ball Pos', (320, 240))

Is there somebody who can explain the reason of that, also a way to maintain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually they are on the same position, when you are drawing an image, the point (320, 240) is the top left pixel of the image, this means that if you draw an image on (0, 0) you will see it on top left side of the screen.

When drawing a circle using pygame.draw.circle the point you specify becomes the center of the circle. if you draw the ball using an image they will appear on same position, also if you want to draw the circle on the center of the hero (as the image shows) you can draw it on (320 +(player.width/2), 240 +(player.height/2).

Also about the GameOver conditions, I don't know if I understood right, usually if you want the player to lose when touching the ball you want a [Collision detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection), when player and ball moves independently like in Super Mario (the screenshot looks like a Super Mario clone so I assume that) and it's impossible for both player and ball to get to the same position, you should rather check if they touch.

I'd strongly suggest changing from the pygame's circle function to an image drawing, it's easier if you want better graphics and it's cheaper on CPU when you are using Collision.

Comment: Thanks you saved a lot for me to understand this, also wish you luck with your games in the google store :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you too have fun with pygame! I used to use it and it's a lot of fun!